# Firefox: Img title doesn't show on hover in a Google Maps info window

Tags: firefox, google-maps

Using bindInfoWindowHtml to create an info window on a Google map, any images in the info window with a title attribute don't show it on hover in Firefox 3.6.  They do show up correctly in IE8 and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

No resolution, but here is the bug:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2480

Update: current status at google site

**Status:**     WontFix

**Closed:**      Mar 2011